# Get and install specific php version with aptitude

Tags: php, debian, installation, php-7, aptitude

Today, current PHP version is Php7.0.8 and I would like get and install Php7.0.5 with aptitude. For example, it's possible with the dotdeb repository ?

How I can get specific php version with aptitude on Debian 8 Jessie ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would probably get a better answer on [Linux & Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, you can use dotdeb: https://www.dotdeb.org/2016/06/24/php-7-0-8-for-jessie/ and https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/

Comment: No I can't, because I would like php 7.0.5 for jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install php7.0.5 with  :

- First, get archive for install :

  ```
  wget http://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.0.5.tar.xz
  ```
- Next, extract the file :

  ```
  tar xvfJ php-7.0.5.tar.xz
  ```
- Go into directory extracted :

  ```
  cd php-7.0.5
  ```
- Configure your installation ([You can help with the online php documentation installation configuration option](http://php.net/manual/fr/configure.about.php))

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=/usr        \
      --sysconfdir=/etc            \
      --localstatedir=/var         \
      --datadir=/usr/share/php     \
      --mandir=/usr/share/man      \
      --enable-fpm                 \
      --with-fpm-user=www-data     \
      --with-fpm-group=www-data    \
      --with-config-file-path=/etc \
      --enable-fastcgi             \
      --enable-ftp
  ```
- Install :

  ```
  make

  make test

  make install
  ```
- Install php.ini :

  ```
  install -v -m644 php.ini-production /etc/php.ini && mv -v /etc/php-fpm.conf{.default,}
  ```

You should obtain output like that :

- `php -v` :

> PHP 7.0.5-1~dotdeb+8.1 (cli) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

- `php-fpm -v`:

> PHP 7.0.5-1~dotdeb+8.1 (fpm-fcgi)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies